# Diacritic characters showing as corrupted symbols when not running on the simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mobile

I'm having a hard time figuring this out, I'm building a SQL request in a method with NSStrings parameters. One such parameter can have diacritic characters (àéèç... etc) but they show as corrupted symbols when I'm testing with an actual Iphone (in simulator it's fine... which is why I can't figure it out). For example in my SQL statement I can have something like `WHERE table.column = 'Carouge √† √©paulettes'`, which really should be "Carouge à épaulettes".

Outputting something with NSLog like so:

```
NSLog(@"Carouge à épaulettes");
```

Still shows corrupted characters in the output console(except in simulator where it's fine).

`NSString`s have the same problem:

```
NSString *diacriticString = @"Carouge à épaulettes";
NSLog(@"%@",diacriticString);
```

I've also tried in an empty project, to see if it could be some custom settings and that didn't work either.

If anyone have suggestions, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Update : Upon further inspection the SQL is correctly constructed, the bug is only a console output issue. Still, if anyone would like to tackle it I'd really love to understand why this is happening.